# Problem with Facebook Login Firebase on Android - E/GraphResponse

Tags: android

I'm trying to create a login activity with facebook on Firebase, but when I try to login, it's says "authentication failed" and I get this error:

> E/GraphResponse: {HttpStatus: 400, errorCode: 100, subErrorCode: 33, errorType: GraphMethodException, errorMessage: Unsupported get
>   request. Object with ID 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx' does not exist, cannot be
>   loaded due to missing permissions, or does not support this operation.

This is my code:

```
         @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    mCallbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
}

private void updateUI() {

    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Logado!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ScreenActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);

}

     public void fbClicked(View view) {

    fbButton = findViewById(R.id.facebookButton);
    fbButton.setEnabled(false);
    LoginManager.getInstance().logInWithReadPermissions(MainActivity.this, Arrays.asList("email", "public_profile"));
    LoginManager.getInstance().registerCallback(mCallbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
            Log.d(TAG, "facebook:onSuccess:" + loginResult);
            handleFacebookAccessToken(loginResult.getAccessToken());
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancel() {
            Log.d(TAG, "facebook:onCancel");
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(FacebookException error) {
            Log.d(TAG, "facebook:onError", error);
        }
    });
}

 @Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    mCallbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}

 private void handleFacebookAccessToken(AccessToken token) {
        Log.d(TAG, "handleFacebookAccessToken:" + token);

        AuthCredential credential = FacebookAuthProvider.getCredential(token.getToken());
        mAuth.signInWithCredential(credential)
                .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                            // Sign in success, update UI with the signed-in user's information
                            Log.d(TAG, "signInWithCredential:success");
                            FirebaseUser user = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
                            fbButton.setEnabled(true);

                            updateUI();
                        } else {
                            // If sign in fails, display a message to the user.
                            Log.w(TAG, "signInWithCredential:failure", task.getException());
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Authentication failed.",
                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                            fbButton.setEnabled(true);

                        }

                    }
                });
}
}
```

Comment: If you are sure that you have done all correctly following documentation maybe the issue is not on your side. Today Facebook announced that they were under hacking attack and probably data of many users leaked so, I'm just guessing, that maybe they temporary suspended some actions.